# What are the uses of ruby's Hash.replace or Array.replace?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, replace

I always see replace in the Array and Hash documentation and I always think that it's odd.

I'm sure I've done something like this many times:

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

...

if some_condition
    a = [:e, :f]
end
```

But I never thought to use this instead:

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

...

if some_condition
    a.replace [:e, :f]
end
```

Which I assume is the intended use. Does this really save memory, or have some other benefit, or is it just a style thing?

Comment: I wonder how often this is used in the wild, e.g. in Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the intended use is to modify an array in-place that has been passed to a method. For example:

```
def m(a)
    a.replace(%w[a b])
end

a = %w[x y z]
m(a)
# a is now ['a', 'b']
```

Without `replace`, you'd have to do something like this:

```
def m(a)
    a.clear
    a << 'a' # or use .push of course
    a << 'b'
end
```

Using `replace` lets you do it all at once should bypass the auto-shrinking and auto-growing (which probably involves copying some memory) behavior that would be a side effect of replacing the array's content (not the array itself!) element by element. The performance benefit (if any) is probably just an extra, the primary intent is probably to get pointer-to-pointer behavior without having to introduce pointers or wrap the array in an extra object.

Answer (score 6):

a = [:e, :f]  and a.replace [:e, :f],

the two statements generated instructions as follows:

1.

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
a = [:e, :f]
```

instructions:

> *ruby --dump=insns test.rb*
>
> ```
> == disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<main>@test.rb>=================
> local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1] s1)
> [ 2] a
> 0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
> 0002 duparray         [:a, :b, :c, :d]
> 0004 setdynamic       a, 0
> 0007 trace            1                                               (   2)
> 0009 duparray         [:e, :f]
> 0011 dup
> 0012 setdynamic       a, 0
> 0015 leave
> ```

2.

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
a.replace([:e, :f])
```

instructions:

> *ruby --dump=insns test.rb*
>
> ```
> == disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<main>@test.rb>=================
> local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1] s1)
> [ 2] a
> 0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
> 0002 duparray         [:a, :b, :c, :d]
> 0004 setdynamic       a, 0
> 0007 trace            1                                               (   2)
> 0009 getdynamic       a, 0
> 0012 duparray         [:e, :f]
> 0014 send             :replace, 1, nil, 0, <ic:0>
> 0020 leave
> ```

The **replace** method is not faster than assignment operator, but **replace** can modify receiver array in-place, and, **replace** method really save memory, this can be seen from rb_ary_replace's source.

> ```
> VALUE
> rb_ary_replace(VALUE copy, VALUE orig)
> {
> rb_ary_modify_check(copy);
> orig = to_ary(orig);
> if (copy == orig) return copy;
>
> if (RARRAY_LEN(orig) <= RARRAY_EMBED_LEN_MAX)
> {
>     VALUE *ptr;
>     VALUE shared = 0;
>
>     if (ARY_OWNS_HEAP_P(copy))
>     {
>         xfree(RARRAY_PTR(copy));
>     }
>     else if (ARY_SHARED_P(copy))
>     {
>         shared = ARY_SHARED(copy);
>         FL_UNSET_SHARED(copy);
>     }
>     FL_SET_EMBED(copy);
>     ptr = RARRAY_PTR(orig);
>     MEMCPY(RARRAY_PTR(copy), ptr, VALUE, RARRAY_LEN(orig));
>     if (shared)
>     {
>         rb_ary_decrement_share(shared);
>     }
>     ARY_SET_LEN(copy, RARRAY_LEN(orig));
> }
> else
> {
>     VALUE shared = ary_make_shared(orig);
>     if (ARY_OWNS_HEAP_P(copy))
>     {
>         xfree(RARRAY_PTR(copy));
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         rb_ary_unshare_safe(copy);
>     }
>     FL_UNSET_EMBED(copy);
>     ARY_SET_PTR(copy, RARRAY_PTR(orig));
>     ARY_SET_LEN(copy, RARRAY_LEN(orig));
>     rb_ary_set_shared(copy, shared);
> }
> return copy; }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
b = [:x, :y, :z]
a.replace(b)

a.object_id == b.object_id
=> false

a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
b = [:x, :y, :z]
a = b

a.object_id == b.object_id
=> true
```

Also

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
c = a
b = [:x, :y, :z]
a.replace(b)
p c # => [:x, :y, :z]
```

vs

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
c = a
b = [:x, :y, :z]
a = b
p c # => [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

This does not answer your question exactly.